# I will give you the money after my parents [give it/have given] it to me?

Tags: tenses

I will be giving something to someone after I get it from elsewhere.

> I will give you the money after my parents give it to me.
>
> I will give you the money after my parents have given it to me.

Which one is the correct?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and to review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to write good questions by the standards of StackExchange. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Both the present and the present perfect may be used in a subordinate clause when the verb in the main clause is in the future tense.  So either of your example sentences is permissible.

Additionally, the present perfect indicates that the first action will be completed before the next occurs.  So it might be stylistically preferable to use "have given" with "after".

> I will give you the money **after** my parents **have given** it to me.
>
> I will give you the money **when** my parents **give** it to me.

Sources:

- [English Grammar - Tenses in subordinate clauses](http://www.englishgrammar.org/tenses-subordinate-clauses/)
- [English Practice - Perfect tenses in subordinate clauses](http://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/perfect-tenses-subordinate-clauses/)